# How to return a singleton list in an API?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

I am in the middle of learning to create a Java API using Eclipse IDE and Spring-Boot framework. Therefore, I am facing a syntax issue which I am not able to resolve. Below is my code for your reference:

```
package first.microservice.moviecatalogservice.resources;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import first.microservice.moviecatalogservice.models.CatalogItem;

@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {
        
    @RequestMapping("/{user_id}")   
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("user_id") String user_id)
        {
            return Collections.singletonList(
                     <CatalogItem> new CatalogItem(name: "DonJon", desc: "Test", rating: 4)
                    );
        }
}
```

Another code which has the CatalogItem class:

```
package first.microservice.moviecatalogservice.models;

public class CatalogItem {

    private String Name;
    private String Desc;
    private int Rating;
    
    public CatalogItem(String name, String desc, int rating) {
        Name = name;
        Desc = desc;
        Rating = rating;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return Desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        Desc = desc;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return Rating;
    }
    public void setRating(int rating) {
        Rating = rating;
    }
    
    
}
```

I wish to enter the URL pattern to display the hardcoded values of the catalogitem to display on the browser.

I am facing error in the following line:

```
return Collections.singletonList(
                     <CatalogItem> new CatalogItem(name: "DonJon", desc: "Test", rating: 4)
                    );
```

The error states that:

```
The method singletonList(T) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (CatalogItem)

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "<", invalid Expression
    - Syntax error on token ":", invalid     AssignmentOperator
    - name cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token ":", invalid     AssignmentOperator
    - desc cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token ":", invalid     AssignmentOperator
    - rating cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: What is the exact issue are you facing? Are you getting some compile time error. Please share your log/Error to understand it better.

Comment: what is the URL u are calling from browser ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK Java doesn't support named parameters. Therefore, this line

```
<CatalogItem> new CatalogItem(name: "DonJon", desc: "Test", rating: 4)
```

will give the syntax error you're facing. Change it for

```
new CatalogItem("DonJon", "Test", 4)
```

And it should work

Comment: Yup you got it, he is facing the same issue :)

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "<", invalid 
  Expression
 - Syntax error on token "<", delete this 
  token
 - CatalogItem cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

Comment: Having issues stated above ^ @Pelocho

Comment: Yep, just noticed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse,

1. Click on **Windows > Preferences**, and then choose **Maven** in the left side.
2. Check the box **Download repository index updates on startup**.

   - Optionally, check the boxes **Download Artifact Sources** and **Download Artifact JavaDoc.**
3. Click OK. The warning won't appear anymore.
4. Restart Eclipse.

Comment: I am facing same issue in Intellij what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is an compile time error in your `getCatalog` method. Please change the return statement like below:

```
public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("user_id") String user_id)
        {
            return Collections.singletonList(new CatalogItem("DonJon", "Test", 4));
        }
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "<", invalid 
  Expression
 - Syntax error on token "<", delete this 
  token
 - CatalogItem cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

Comment: I am getting a red line under the CatalogItem name, and getting the following error as stated above.

Comment: Yep, just noticed. Thanks.